# "error establishing a database connection" windows azure + wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cloud, azure-sql-database

I am the owner of http://www.netzkino.de (the wordpress-website is running on azure).

Mostly all works fine, but under last, I got the message "error establishing a database connection".

I guess there are to many database-queries.. (over 10k unique visitors per day). I tried also to scale the instances without success... :/

How can I fix this problem? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,

Daniel

Comment: Do you use Wordpress caching? Do you have shared hosting?

Comment: Hi Jurgo, yes I use caching and I use reserved instances (no sharing instances).

Comment: I have the same issue (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/a9a02261-85e1-4f87-97dd-cf08e9e58548)

Answer (score 0):

```
Daniel Schmidt Check wp-config.php file.
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now your site working fine there is no error, but i got your problem, some times when there is maintenance in hosting that time Database problem occur...[image]

Comment: Hi shubh, thx for your reply. So the problem is windows azure itself?:(